# react native json response check if string or object

Tags: json, react-native, fetch

sorry for the silly question. I am relatively new to react native. I have got fetch working so I can get the json response back from the server. The server API returns a string if there is an error or returns an json object if its successful. is there any way to compare the response to see if its a string or json variable?

Not sure how to achieve the above any help would be appreciated.

here is my code

API.js

```
var API = {

   SetupBuyOnline(email, serialNumber, platformType) {
        var url = 'https://<urlomitted>/SetupBuyOnline';
        return fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'operating_system': platformType,
                'email': email,
                'serialNumber': serialNumber
            }
        }).then((res) => res.json());
    }
};
```

find userScreen.js

```
  findUserScreen(){
    // this.props.navigation.navigate('JoinNowScreen')
    StudentApi.SetupBuyOnline('useremail@test.com', deviceId, "iOS")
    .then((responseData) => {
      if(typeof(responseData) == 'string')
      {
        console.log('got api call ' + responseData);
        alert('test = ' + responseData);
      }
      else
      {
        console.log('got api call ' + responseData);
        alert(responseData);
      }
    })
  }
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than changing your `==` for `===` (strict equality) not much. But will work with normal equality.

Dont know what you're doing wrong, because this code works just fine.

What I would do instead is having a JSON response like so:

```
"{
    error: true,
}"


"{
    error: false,
    data: yourDataSentByTheServer!
}"
```

That way you only need to check if there's an error property inside your JSON response.

```js
function stringType(){
  const responseData = 'hello';
  if(typeof(responseData) === 'string')
  {
    console.log('got api call ' + responseData);
    alert('test = ' + responseData);
  }
  else
  {
    console.log('got api call ' + responseData);
    alert(responseData);
  }
}

function objType(){
  const responseData = { 1:'hello', 2: 'koko' }
  if(typeof(responseData) === 'string')
  {
    console.log('got api call ' + responseData);
    alert('test = ' + responseData);
  }
  else
  {
    console.log('got api call ' + responseData);
    alert(responseData);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="stringType();">Click me for string</button>
<button onClick="objType();">Click me for obj</button>
```

Comment: weird. when I tried before it didnt detect it as a string. Anyway thanks for your help :)

Comment: Alright :) but consider my option for your JSON, its a good approach to keep things concise :)